# Spring Eureka dynamic service lookup

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

Very new to Spring/Eureka, sorry if this is a dumb question:

I have multiple services, all implementing a common interface. I need to dynamically (at runtime) select the correct implementation. For example, I may have a front end that services multiple payroll systems. I want to select the correct payroll system based on some attribute.

I don't want to have to define multiple endpoints for each (if I start servicing an additional system, I don't want to have to add even more endpoints).

What I ***want*** to do is locate the correct service (maybe construct the name dynamically based on the desired payroll system) and interact via the interface. 
Does that make sense? Possible? Obvious?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for auto-configuration.

Take a look here [Creating your own auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write your custom router strategy with `Spring Cloud Netflix` which can deliver your request to different microservice according to your rule .